# Opam Depext tezos command error when building node from sources

Tags: node, tezos-client

Please help me out, I'm building from source https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html

````
    # Detecting depexts using vars: arch=x86_64, os=linux, os-distribution=ubuntu, os-family=debian
    [ERROR] Sorry, resolution of the request timed out.
            Try to specify a simpler request, use a different solver, or increase the allowed time by setting OPAMSOLVERTIMEOUT to a bigger value (currently, it is set to 60.0 seconds).```
    Command failed: opam list --readonly --external  '--resolve=tezos' returned 60
````

Comment: I don't think it's a fix, but it helped increasing the timeout: so `export OPAMSOLVERTIMEOUT=300`

Answer (score 1):

At the time I'm writing this is a known issue in Tezos' codebase. Developers are working to fix this issue. It is fine setting `export OPAMSOLVERTIMEOUT=300` as a temporary workaround, but beware it may not suffice; I'm regularly using `OPAMSOLVERTIMEOUT=6000`. For a more robust workaround, apply the following patch (taken from [this commit](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/commit/aa4218126b37cfedeeb735443374214f4021d866?merge_request_iid=1943) that isn't on `master`):

```
diff --git a/src/tooling/tezos-tooling.opam b/src/tooling/tezos-tooling.opam
index e69888491..b0d9a8633 100644
--- a/src/tooling/tezos-tooling.opam
+++ b/src/tooling/tezos-tooling.opam
@@ -8,6 +8,11 @@ license: "MIT"
 depends: [
   "coq-of-ocaml" { = "2.2.1" }
   "dune" { >= "2.0" }
+  "irmin" { = "2.2.0" }
+  "lwt" { = "5.3.0" }
+  "ocaml" { = "4.09.1" }
+  "ocaml-base-compiler" { = "4.09.1" }
+  "yojson" { = "1.7.0" }
   "ocamlformat" { = "0.10" }
   "bisect_ppx" { >= "2.3" }
 ]
```

that reduces the size of the constraints problem that opam's solver tackles.

[edit] Issue is now fixed, thanks to this commit: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/commit/a07e391fd80a397be380de4b99b796aa530523ee Building a version after this commit should not cause a timeout anymore.